# Im learning to make a bot using python. What do I do so that I can create a new channel using the commands?

Tags: python, discord, bots

Thanks for the previous people that helped me for the last question
What Im trying to do is make a different file for a function which is when you type "!Create" + (The name I want the channel to be) it creates a new channel with a specified name and I want that file to be able called back in the main channel

Code 1 :

```
import os
import discord
import createchannel

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

commands = {
    '$Hello' : 'Hello! write "$Help" to find more about the CazB0T ',
    '$Help' : 'Hi again! The CazB0T is still in beta stages...the only 5 commands are $Hello, $Help, $Test1, $Test2, and $Test3',
    '$Test1' : 'This is Test1',
    '$Test2' : 'This is Test2',
    '$Test3' : 'This is Test3'
}

createchannel()

my_secret = os.environ['token']

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: 
        return

    for key, value in commands.items():
        if message.content.startswith(key):
            await message.channel.send(value)



client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Code 2:

```
import discord
import os
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_chancreate(channel):
  channelname = input()
  if channel.content == "!create" + channelname:
    channel = await channel.create_text_channel(channelname)

client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Comment: 1. I'd recommend using separate functions for each command - doable with proper decorator - instead of listening to every message. 2. Even if you handle them in on_message, that's not the best to way to search the dict - you do it lineary, O(n), while dict keys can be searched in O(1). 3. Bot cannot handle `input` - that's console function. 4. `"!create" + channelname` would not have a space between them.

Comment: How do I make it so I can create a new channel with a specified name using commands?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I assume you want to create a channel via a command. To accomplish this you need to consider a few things:

If you want to use `commands` you have to change `client = discord.Client()` to `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix")` and import `commands` from `discord.ext`:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") # Example prefix
```

**First:** You have to set up conditions, which have to be fulfilled. You want to be able to give the channel its own name? Assume this as the required argument:

```py
@client.command()
async def cchannel(ctx, *, name):
```

- We said that `name` is a required argument.
- `*` is used so that we can also inpute names like `t e s t` and not only `test`.

**Second:** You need to define the guild where you want to create the channel. To do that we use:

```py
guild = ctx.message.guild
```

Finally we want to [create a text channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel). **To do this we use:**

```py
@client.command()
async def channel(ctx, *, name):
    guild = ctx.message.guild # Get the guild
    await guild.create_text_channel(name=name) # Create a text channel based on the input
    await ctx.send(f"Created a new channel with the name `{name}`") # Optional
```

- While creating the channel we said that the name should be our required argument `name`.