# discord.py - Guessing game no response

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The following code is supposed to be executed when `$play` is typed into a channel on my Discord Server but the bot doesn't respond or react in any way.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command(name="play")
async def play(ctx):
  def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel

  number = random.randint(1,100)
  await ctx.send('I have a number in mind between 1 and 100, guess it')

  for i in range(0,5):
    guess = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    
    if guess.content > number:
      await ctx.send("The number is greater")
    elif guess.content < number:
      await ctx.send("The number is smaller")
    elif guess.content == number:
      await ctx.send("You guessed the number!!")
    else:
      return ("It has to be a positive integer between 1 to 100")
  else:
    await ctx.send("You lost, type $play to play again.")
```

Comment: Do you have a `on_message` event in your code?

Comment: @Chuaat Where exactly (what position) should I add the ```on_message``` event?

Comment: You shouldn’t, the `on_message` event has nothing to do with your question at all, there’s a simple logic error in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Guessing game, discord.py bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361326/guessing-game-discord-py-bot)

Answer (score 3):

Because there’s a logic error in your code, in all the if/elif statements you’re checking if `guess.content` (a string) is less/higher/equal than an integer, that’s never true, then in your else statement you’re not sending anything at all (you’re returning, exiting out of the function instead of sending the actual message).

```py
@client.command(name="play")
async def play(ctx):
  def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel

  number = random.randint(1,100)
  await ctx.send('I have a number in mind between 1 and 100, guess it')

  for i in range(0,5):
    guess = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    
    if int(guess.content) > number:
      await ctx.send("The number is greater")
    elif int(guess.content) < number:
      await ctx.send("The number is smaller")
    elif int(guess.content) == number:
      await ctx.send("You guessed the number!!")
    else:
      await ctx.send("It has to be a positive integer between 1 to 100")
  else:
    await ctx.send("You lost, type $play to play again.")
```

This will throw an error if the message doesn’t contain a number, you should add another statement in your check

```py
def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel and m.content.isdigit()
```

Comment: I have made the changes you mentioned but the bot still doesn't respond on typing ```$play```.. Here is the replit [link](https://replit.com/@fs0c13ty/Mr-Robot#main.py) to the program.

Comment: The other commands in the code work; I am using @client.event for them. Here is the link once more if you missed it on my previous edit: https://replit.com/@fs0c13ty/Mr-Robot#main.py

Comment: Then why have you decided to use `bot.command ` for this one? You should also change it from `bot.wait_for` to `client.wait_for`

Comment: @Elmo If you want to use `commands` you have to change some things in your code. I made an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67317646/im-learning-to-make-a-bot-using-python-what-do-i-do-so-that-i-can-create-a-new/67325403#67325403) to that a while ago. You also **can't** use `bot` and `client`, decide on one and define it.